# jquery, callback function in a focus()

Tags: jquery, callback, focus

I have a callback function inside a focus() but as long as my element has the focus, the function keeps playing, is it a way for the function to be played just one time ?

for exemple in this code the alert('ok') will come until the textearea will lose the focus. Is it a way to play the alert just one time?

```
<textarea></textarea>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

$(function () {

    $('textarea').focus(function(){
        alert('ok');
    }); 

});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/manguo_manguo/9utcy/

Comment: why you want to play alert. offcourse it will loos focus when we click alert and focus on textarea again.. write other code here and don't play with it.. i hope your original logic doen't have any alert in it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your jQuery to use the `one()` function.

Here's the code:

```
$(function () {

    $('textarea').one('focus', function(){
        alert('ok');
    }); 

});
```

And here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9utcy/1/

Answer (score 2):

It is not that the functions keeps playing, it is that you automatically take out the focus from the control in order to click in the alert, and then the focus go back to the control, firing the focus event once again, try to test with anything else besides the alert.